# Iteration in pug erroring out

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

EDIT ADDED [GIST](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/354693058ecc00d27a73ba5802e5a09a)

I am having difficulty using pug to iterate through an array of Objects:

**app.render**

```
response.render('layout', {
    title: 'Visual Display',
    slides: shuffledData
});
```

**layout.pug**

```
html
    head
        title= title
    body
        each slide in slides
            p= slide.type
```

**Error Message**

```js
TypeError: /home/chris/Projects/visualdisplay/src/views/layout.pug:6
   4|     body
   5|         each slide in slides
 > 6|             p= slide.type

Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
   at eval (eval at wrap (/home/chris/Projects/visualdisplay/node_modules/pug-runtime/wrap.js:6:10), <anonymous>:23:62)
```

If I change the reponse.render to a response.send (to see the data being sent) I get:
*I have redacted some of the data values in the example*

```js
[{
    "type": "achievement",
    "studentCode": 110399,
    "studentFirstName": "xx",
    "studentMiddleName": "xx",
    "studentLastName": "xx",
    "studentHouse": "Eagles",
    "achievementType": "Academic",
    "achievementDescription": "well done in house point competition in maths",
    "achievementDate": "2017-02-23T00:00:00.000Z",
    "staffPreferredFirstName": "",
    "staffFirstName": "xx",
    "staffLastName": "xx"
}, {
    "type": "achievement",
    "studentCode": 102797,
    "studentFirstName": "xx",
    "studentMiddleName": "xx",
    "studentLastName": "xx",
    "studentHouse": "Oryx",
    "achievementType": "Academic",
    "achievementDescription": "Well done in revision Kahoot on exponents and natural logs",
    "achievementDate": "2017-02-23T00:00:00.000Z",
    "staffPreferredFirstName": "",
    "staffFirstName": "xx",
    "staffLastName": "xx"
}, {
    "type": "tweet",
    "user": {
        "name": "xx",
        "screenName": "xx",
        "description": "",
        "profileImage": "xx"
    },
    "tweet": {
        "date": "Mon Feb 20 16:21:04 +0000 2017",
        "text": "xx",
        "mediaURL": "xx"
    }
}]
```

If I change the pug code to something like

```
html
    head
        title= title
    body
        each slide in slides
            p testline
```

It does iterate over the correct amount of times for the datasheet being sent in slides.

Additionally if i do something like p= slides[0].type it will correctly find the value.

I am using the latest pug and express from npm.

What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Use this, you can set vars with `-`, then you print value with `#{varName}`, if you want to render the value (for example you've got some html tags), you can use `!{varName}`

```
 html
 head
        title= title
    body
        each slide in slides
          -slideType = slide.type
           #{slideType}
```

As a simple working example you can use externals jade (pug) to html converters:

```
-slides = [{"id":"1", "type":"html", "value":"<strong>strong text</strong>"}, {"id":"2", "type":"plain-text", "value":"plain text"}]

    each slide in slides
       div !{slide.value}
       div #{slide.value}
```

Comment: I get the same error Cannot read property 'type' of undefined